# Showing $\int_C\frac{f'(z)}{z-z_0}dz=\int_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

**$f$ is analytic everywhere on and inside a simple closed contour $C.$ Let $z_0$ be a point interior to $C.$ Then I've shown $\int_C\dfrac{f'(z) dz}{z-z_0}=\int_C\dfrac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^2}$ as follows:**

$f$ is analytic everywhere on and inside $C\implies f'$ is analytic everywhere on and inside $C.$ Then $2\pi i f'(z_0)=\int_C\dfrac{f'(z)dz}{(z-z_0)}$ and $2\pi if'(z_0)=\int_C\dfrac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^2}.$

Am I right?

Comment: It looks fine **when** you assume the Cauchy's Integral Theorem, which makes the question pretty simple.

Comment: Yep I have used Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also argue this by using laurent series. Let $$
  f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^k
$$ be the taylor expansion of $f$ around $z_0$. Since $f$ is analytic on $C$ and its interior, the series converges there, and does so in a way that allows differentiation and summation to be swapped. It follows that $$
\begin{align}
 \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2} &= \sum_{k=-2}^\infty a_{k+2} (z-z_0)^k \\
 f'(z) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k+1} (k+1)(z-z_0)^k \\
 \frac{f'(z)}{z-z_0} &= \sum_{k=-1}^\infty a_{k+2} (k+2)(z-z_0)^k
\end{align}
$$
By the residue theorem, $\int_C \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k(z-z_0)^k = i2\pi c_{-1}$ if $z_0$ lies within $C$ and $C$ is simple and closed. Thus $$
  \int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2} = \int_C \frac{f'(z)}{z-z_0}
$$
exactly if the coefficients of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ in the laurent expansions of both integrands are the same. By the above, they're both $a_1$, qed.

Comment: Whoever downvoted might want to explain why....