# If f is analytic on the simple closed contour C, then $\oint_C(f' (z))/((z-z_0 )dz= \oint_C f(z)/(z-z_0 )^2 dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

If f is analytic within and on the simple closed contour C and z_0  is a point within C,then
 $$\oint_C\frac{f' (z)}{z-z_0 }dz= \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0 )^2} dz$$

Is this statement true or false? If true why and if false why?

I tried to use Cauchy's integral formula but I couldn't prove true or false.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/378134/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2404266/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2166543/42969 – all found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Coint_C%5Cfrac%7Bf%27%20(z)%7D%7Bz-z_0%20%7Ddz%3D%20%5Coint_C%20%5Cfrac%7Bf(z)%7D%7B(z-z_0%20)%5E2%7D%20dz%24&p=1)

Comment: Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f'$ is analytic also. By [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), both integrals are equal to $2\pi i \,f'(z_0)$.